# Why after selected when hover back to original color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight

It returns back to the original color even if selected when hover on it.
Why? How can I fix it?

This is the xaml:
I think it because the animation called even if it selected and canceled the selected color.

```
<Style x:Key="AcountComboItemContailner" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
  <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".35" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor"/>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".35" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor"/>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Fill="White" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
          <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Fill="White" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
          <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
          <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Is it WPF or Silverlight? To me it looks like Silverlight. You should be specific about the technology/framework or you won't get useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one element with the name *fillColor*, and you have two different VisualStates that both manipulate it. And each of those states will set the opacity to `0.35` while active, and each of them will set it back to `0.00` as soon as the state is going inactive again.

You need to have separate elements to indicate the respective states with. Otherwise your states will always mess with each others visual representation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Style x:Key="AcountComboItemContailner" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor2"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="#4D4D4D"
                                                                KeyTime="0" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".35"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor2"/>-->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="#4D4D4D"
                                                                KeyTime="0" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".35" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor"/>-->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Fill="Transparent" IsHitTestVisible="False"  Opacity="1" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Fill="Transparent" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="1" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

thanks this is actually the solution!